# Why isn't a Kotlin const val recognized as compile-time constant when indirectly referenced?

Tags: android, kotlin

Say I've got a class

```
@SomeAnnotation(someValue = A_CONST_VAL)
class SomeClass {
    companion object {
        const val A_CONST_VAL = "a constant value"
    }
    ...
}
```

The above compiles fine - no issues. However, if I want to use `A_CONST_VAL` in a constants file...

```
import some.package.SomeClass.A_CONST_VAL

object SomeConstants {
    const val CONSTRUCTED_CONST_VAL = "some stuff ${A_CONST_VAL}"
}
```

and use `CONSTRUCTED_CONST_VAL` as the compile-time annotation value, such that the previous class is now

```
@SomeAnnotation(someValue = SomeConstants.CONSTRUCTED_CONST_VAL)
class SomeClass {
    companion object {
        const val A_CONST_VAL = "a constant value"
    }
    ...
}
```

The compiler thinks that the supplied annotation value is not a compile-time constant.

What gives?

Note: I've also tried implementing the file holding constants as Java, just to see if it worked

```
class SomeConstants {
    public static final String CONSTRUCTED_CONST_VAL = "a constant value" + SomeClass.A_CONST_VAL;
}
```

still a compilation failure

Comment: Which Kotlin version are you using? I tried it and it works just fine with 1.2.31: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/k9h40tnmvgl06hej8uu6n9u1jc/6t716dipoi8bl8bjbv60a0vb02

Comment: Currently 1.2.21. I don't have the luxury of updating the Kotlin version on this project at the moment.

Comment: @saganut Well, the sample I shared above works even with 1.1.60 (there's a switch on the Try Kotlin site). Can you try to reproduce the problem in a clean project or provide more details about it?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it in a clean project and post it when I get some time.

Comment: You have a circular dependency here. But it should still work...